# How to calculate the sum amount of parent field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

Hi I have denormalized the data to be flat in elasticsearch.

e.g.

```
{childId: 123, childAmount: 3.4, parentId: 1, parentAmount: 5.6}
{childId: 234, childAmount: 4.4, parentId: 1, parentAmount: 5.6}
{childId: 345, childAmount: 5.4, parentId: 2, parentAmount: 1.2}
```

See there are 3 children and 2 identical parent.
How to calulate the sum amount of parentAmount (which should be 6.8)?

Thanks. And if possible, how to use kibana metric visual to show this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kibana you can do it like this using a Metric visualization:

[image]

And with a query like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "per_parent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parentId",
        "size": 25
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max": {
          "max": {
            "field": "parentAmount"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_amounts": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "per_parent>max"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the man. That's exactly what I am looking for. give you 5 stars

Comment: Also may I know what ES version are you using? I found that `sum bucket` appear in 6.0 but not in 5.1 in my side. Thanks

Comment: Oh. I used the latest 5.6 version (I saw that you used the `kibana-5` tag in your post).

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Note that there is a limit, say L, on the number of buckets that can be returned in the "terms" aggregation (I think the default L is around 65000, if I understood correctly). If your number of parents is over L then you will be getting wrong results using this approach, as there will be documents that will not be able to fall into one of those L buckets.